# Changing clicking element's style

Tags: javascript, css, dom

Here is very newbie problem.
There is three options like checkbox in [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/hvWeG/3/).
When the option is clicked, i want to change background color of clicked option like checkbox.
I couldn't figure out the problem due to the id of the options are same which is `option`.

Comment: Having multiple elements in the DOM with the same id is not valid

Comment: The id attribute should be unique. Use the class attribute instead.

Comment: @PeeHaa If i set differents ids for each element how can i handle css? Am i have to set #option style for every different id?

Comment: Use actual checkboxes and style with CSS.

Answer (score 2):

A possible implementation in query could be:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".myCheckboxClass").bind('click', function(){
        $(this).css('background-color', 'red');
    });

});
```

You can basically do the same in js, just check the proper syntax. The key thing is the "this" selection of the clicked element.

Answer (score 1):

use `class` instead of `id`, since (as its name already says) `id` must be unique, otherwise it is not an id anymore..

repaired and working version: http://jsfiddle.net/hvWeG/5/

```
$(function(){
  $('.option').on('click',function(){
   $(this).css('background-color','yellow');
  });
});
```

html

```
<ul style="display:block;" id="options">
    <li class="option">Cucumber</li>
    <li class="option">Tomato</li>
    <li class="option">Potato</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

Check this out 
[check edited Code here](http://jsfiddle.net/hvWeG/11/)

1> First of all your fucntion should be in  head,in jsfiddle near the left top corner change the `onload` to `no wrap in head`,

2> you dont need script tag in onclick

3> document.getElementById('option') will select only the first element with id 'option'
Check the following code , i have made some minor changes to your code. 
[check edited Code here](http://jsfiddle.net/hvWeG/11/)